# how to use textarea tags without opening up security

Tags: php, mysql

I know it sounds somehow but have done a bit of search on this even in G and no desired results.

What is the best approach to allow tags in your textarea boxes without opening up security hole in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about filtering data to protect yourself from XSS attacks, etc. You might want to take a look at [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and [please do not consider using regex :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow html tags in your textarea I would recommended strictly restricting allowable tags. For example, you could allow only "em" or "i" tags. Everything else that you don't need should be filtered out.